# useful stepper component with ngForm validate in angular 6

Tags: angular, forms, stepper

I used ngForm validate. I know how to use it. But material stepper with in formGroup validate. So i don't know how to use the formGroup. So please tell me with simple example of formGroup or ngForm validate with in stepper component tell me. Thank you....

Comment: What you have tried so far? what's the error in your code?

Comment: formGroup Error -- **ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'secondCtrl'** _secondCtrl_ is my formControlName. @PardeepJain. ngForm validation is very simple (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760992/ngform-simple-example-in-angular-6-with-select-box/52760993#52760993)

Comment: Bro I know already, I am asking for what code you tried for stepper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help me this link for my requirements (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-9lskal)

That is `[completed]="ngForm.form.valid"` useful my ngForm validation.

And `Linear stepper shows edit icons instead of done icons` issue clear https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8997 that link